# Problem importing from HDF5

Tags: import, data, dataset, python, hdf5-format

I'm trying to import an item from a valid [HDF5](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html) file, but I get this error:

[image]

I can read the metadata, but cannot import the actual tensor dataset:

[image]

And yet it's not an issue with the file's data - as importing (with [h5py](https://www.h5py.org/)) in Python works just fine:

[image]

Perhaps there's a way of importing pieces of the HDF5 file that works?

**Details:**

- Here's a [link to the h5 dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uk5sd3t56feb3jr/validation.h5?dl=0) to try it yourself
- I'm using MMA 11.3 on latest MacOS
- I've already tried using HDF5Tools and GeneralUtilities`MLStorage without any luck.

Comment: The h5 file is about a 1gb. If anyone wants to try processing it I can post it to dropbox...

Comment: Please provide a link to the file. Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @rafalc Ok, I added the link and I'm using 11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the dataset metadata with `h5dump`:

```
$ h5dump -p -H --dataset="/input_image" file.h5

DATASET "input_image" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_U8LE
      (...)
      FILTERS {
         PREPROCESSING SHUFFLE
         USER_DEFINED_FILTER {
            FILTER_ID 32000
            COMMENT lzf
            PARAMS { 4 261 32768 }
         }
      }
   (...)
   }
```

In case of unknown filters Mathematica is a little less informative, as it does not give the name of the filter ("LZF") only the ID:

```
In[15]:= Import["file.h5", {"DataEncoding", "/input_image"}]

Out[15]= {"Shuffle", "Unknown(32000)"}
```

HDF5 comes with a number of predefined [filters](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Filters):

> H5Z_FILTER_DEFLATE    - The gzip compression, or deflation, filter
>   H5Z_FILTER_SZIP       - The SZIP compression filter
>   H5Z_FILTER_NBIT   - The N-bit compression filter
>   H5Z_FILTER_SCALEOFFSET    - The scale-offset compression filter
>   H5Z_FILTER_SHUFFLE    - The shuffle algorithm filter
>   H5Z_FILTER_FLETCHER32 - The Fletcher32 checksum, or error checking,
>   filter

As you can see, LZF is not one of them. It turns out that h5py adds its own filters to whatever is shipped with HDF5. This is how h5py documents the LZF filter:

> "lzf"
>           Custom compression filter for h5py.  This filter is much, much faster
>           than gzip (roughly 10x in compression vs. gzip level 4, and 3x faster
>           in decompressing), but at the cost of a worse compression ratio.  Use
>           this if you want cheap compression **and portability is not a concern**.

In other words, you have a file which uses non-standard compression filter which Mathematica does not understand so it cannot decode the data.

That being said, the error message from Mathematica should be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer. Is there anyway to re-export it from python to make it importable (get rid of the LZF filter)?

Comment: In HDF5 you cannot change filters on the existing dataset. But you can always import a dataset with h5py and export the data to a new dataset without the LZF filter. From what I see, all datasets in your file use LZF so you may want to repeat this action in a loop.